# remove quotes from javascript array

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a javascript with the unixtimestamp and the price of an item at that particular time. The timestamp is coming in string as listed below. How do I remove the double quotes from the timestamp. This is the array. I used the string replace function but not working.

```
["1356998400000", 222.69179362385]
["1357084800000", 209.18952317885]
["1357171200000", 211.95012017103]
["1357257600000", 200.15913266219]
["1357344000000", 215.58462758679]
```

Comment: what it refer to tag `momentjs`?

Comment: Look up how to convert a string into a number.

Comment: Maybe just use `parseInt`?

Comment: I tried to convert the date into unixtime starmp using momentjks and i got that

Comment: Do you want to convert those to moment date variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var myArr = ["1356998400000", 222.69179362385,
"1357084800000", 209.18952317885,
"1357171200000", 211.95012017103,
"1357257600000", 200.15913266219,
"1357344000000", 215.58462758679];

//check the values in the array before making changes
console.log(myArr);

var i;
for(i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  if(typeof myArr[i] == "string") {
    myArr[i] = parseFloat(myArr[i]);
  }
}

//check the value of the array after changes
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [["1356998400000", 222.69179362385],
["1357084800000", 209.18952317885],
["1357171200000", 211.95012017103],
["1357257600000", 200.15913266219],
["1357344000000", 215.58462758679]];

arr.forEach(function(item){
 item[0] = Number(item[0])
})
console.log(arr);
```

Just Use `Number()` to make a string containing number to number.